# Is it possible to generate RF to then harvest instead of just using background RF?

Tags: rf, energy-harvesting

I know you can harvest background RF using energy harvesting techniques but this only generates a small amount of power. Could you put a RF emitter close to an energy harvesting product to get more power. If anyone has any links to research on this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to the forum. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: That’s effectively what contactless phone chargers and RFID tags do already.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am looking at a component that is in a hard to reach area for maintenance so am looking into whether energy harvesting can be used over a battery. Thermal gradients and vibrations may also be able to be harvested but I was just wondering if you could produce RF around the local area to harvest in the hard to reach area.

Comment: I will look more into the RFID tags and contactless phone chargers, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Wireless charging for portables has largely settled on the Qi protocol. Qi works at close range - 4cm or less. Qi could probably be hacked/modified to use a directional emitter to increase its range. More about Qi here: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/equipment-items-gadgets/wireless-battery-charging/qi-wireless-charging-standard.php

Xiaomi has shown a long range charging system, but it's not on the market yet. More here: https://gizmodo.com/xiaomi-announces-a-long-range-wireless-charger-you-prob-1846158088

And finally, here's a chip that does generic RF harvesting: https://www.powercastco.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/PCC110-PCC210-Overview-V1.6-ONE-PAGE.pdf. There's several versions that support different ISM bands.

Comment: Thank you for this. Probably looking a bit further than 4cm, maybe up to 1m but this is really helpful.